# Can data be recovered from a directory wiped out by a compiler's install task?

Tags: linux, software-installation, compiling, data-recovery, uninstall

I cloned `gradle` from `https://github.com/gradle/gradle` and worked on building it on `linux x86_64` (Fedora 37). I did not modify any of the configuration files. As `gradle` finished building, it erased/deleted - seemingly on cleanup - files and folders I had under `$HOME`. I looked under `$HOME/.gradle/caches`, `/tmp`, and Trash, but could not find any of the erased files/folders. I read about the `gradle` directories at `https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html` and could understand that cleanup is done automatically in the build process. I tried the following:

- `testdisk` did not detect the `btrfs` filesystem.
- `btrfs restore ...` recovered only what exists in the directory, but not the lost data/files.

I do not expect any package or compiler to erase/delete material that does not belong to the package itself. I also expect the compiler to ask and let the user decide and further emit a warning message before it erases any files or folders. The issue becomes more serious when such files and folders are system ones.

I assume that `BuildDir`- if recovered - will have the files/folders I lost. Is there a way to recover the `BuildDir` and how? Can `make install` be reversed with `make uninstall`? In general, for any package and any compiler, can the erased data/files be recovered from the directory wiped out by the compiler's `install` task?